# Every single link on my website opens to my last blog post

Tags: templates

Every link has the correct permalink and I can see the correct page in the dashboard, but when I click on view page it goes to the correct permalink but shows the last blog article in the main body. If I click on any of the menu items it goes to the last blog. Not the home page - because the home page is different. It might have to do with I was trying to create a template so every page had the same basic structure but I screwed it up somewhere. see the  pic - different permalink but same page.[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Could you please edit your question and include more details on where and how you created the page template, and what is inculed in it? The screenshots do show that something is wrong, but without knowing what exactly has been done it is rather difficult to find where things went wrong.

Comment: P.s. please note that if this is something you did with WPBakery plugin, then do refer to the plugin's documentation or the contact plugin author for support as questions regarding 3rd party plugins are considered off-topic here.